# Docker container runtime error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, scala, github-actions, vcredist

I am trying to run a service written in Scala in a docker container and when running the service I have the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\\Users\\ContainerAdministrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jni-mt5-17287867478131106707\\mt5_lib.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

This app has a dependency on a library that loads the `mt5-lib.dll` mentioned above.

The exception suggests that I am missing some libraries. What is strange about this problem is that I already encountered this problem while writing the Dockerfile, and solved it by installing the `vc_redist` (https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe).

Still **if I locally build the image and run it, I don't have the mentioned problem**. I only have the problem if I build the image using GitHub actions and push it to Amazon ECR, and then pull it from ECR and run it, which is the way that I want to do it.

The project is written in Scala, version 2.12.7, using sbt version 1.2.7. The Dockerfile is below:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11.0.16.1_1-jdk as deps

ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.12.7
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.2.7
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
ADD https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v1.2.7/sbt-1.2.7.msi sbt-1.2.7.msi

RUN Start-Process 'sbt-1.2.7.msi' '/qn' -PassThru | Wait-Process;

COPY . .

RUN sbt 'project app' universal:packageBin

RUN Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "C:\app\target\universal\app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" -DestinationPath "c:\\"

FROM eclipse-temurin:11.0.16.1_1-jdk

COPY --from=deps /app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ c:/app/

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe" -OutFile "c:\vc_redist.x64.exe"
RUN c:\vc_redist.x64.exe  /install /norestart

RUN New-Item "c:\app\logs" -Type Directory

WORKDIR "c:\app"

ENTRYPOINT ".\start-svc.bat"
```

The build.yaml file for GitHub actions is below:

```
name: App build

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - 'master'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-2019
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Configure AWS
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION_EU_WEST_1 }}
      # Login to ECR
      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
      # Build the Docker image
      - name: Build
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: my/ecr/repo
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.ref_name }}
        run: |-
          docker build -t "$Env:ECR_REGISTRY/$Env:ECR_REPOSITORY`:app-$Env:GITHUB_SHA" -f app\Dockerfile .
          docker push "$Env:ECR_REGISTRY/$Env:ECR_REPOSITORY`:app-$Env:GITHUB_SHA"
```

When I figured out that when I locally build the docker image, it runs with no problems, I really only tried to change the windows image on the GitHub actions from windows-2019 to windows-latest, but that didn't help.

I really don't have any more ideas, so any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Check the Path environment variable after pulling the image from ECR, at the moment that the jvm executes your application it tries to load the dll to execute some native function via jni, if the PATH is not pointing where the dll is located modifiy the .bat to set it with the correct location.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez I checked the Path environment variable after pulling the image from ECR and the path to temp folder where the .dll is located, was not there, but the path was present in the Temp environment variable. However, the environment variables on the locally generated image and the one pulled from the ECR seem to be the same, so I can run it with the locally generated image with the same environment variables. I also added manually the path to the temp folder to Path environment variable, still the same error.